# Android device as USB Accessory

Tags: android, usb

I want to connect Android device to a host device. The android device will work as an accessory as the host will power the bus.  My application code for android looks like:

**Android Manifest**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>

 <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
         android:resource="@xml/usb_xml" />
```

The usb xml looks like: 
*usb_xml*

```
 <resources> 
      <usb-accessory model="Google Inc" manufacturer="0x2D01" version="2.12.1.0"/>   
 </resources>
```

Is it mandatory to have the usb.xml ??

So when I am trying to get the connected USBDevice details, the USB Device list is always null :

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
Map<String,UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
```

Again, I also tried to get the accessory list, the USB accessorylist is also null

```
UsbAccessory[] accessoryList = manager.getAccessoryList();
```

I don't know what is the problem. I am having an HP laptop connected with a Samsung mobile (GellyBean(17) > 12 API)., where HP laptop is the host and Samsung mobile is accesosory

Some one Please help me I am stuck for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iprules of the device were protecting the communication to happen. When I configured the rules properly, communication was happening properly.

Comment: can you please post the way you have configured android device as accessory?

Comment: hey @saby, Can you share the complete code if it worked?

Comment: shaare the code or the steps man

Comment: @sunil the code plz

Comment: @obeid_s The OP should have the code, as he/she answered his/her own post. Also, this happened in 2019 and now I am not in this domain now. Sorry, i do not have the code. OP owner might be able to help, if he/she is still around

Comment: @sunil dont worry man , if u could help here is my Q : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75410351/c-sharp-serialport-with-java-android-phone